# Python get username when active user is root

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use the os module and the getpass module via the getuser() and getlogin() functions. However these are just returning "root" because my script has to run as root. Is it possible that there is another function that is able to get the username on my computer even when my program is being run as root? Or do I have to provide this as some sort of config? This is for UNIX machines, doesn't necessarily have to work on Windows based devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script is running interactively, you should be using `sudo` to run it and in that case, os.getlogin() will give the correct original user, not root.

In other situations, just add a parameter to your script, that's a basic programming task. If you need help on that, update your question to be more specific.